# When saving CSV file, remove first comma in the header

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I used to receive from an external client a bunch of csv like this

```
Queue Title,Queue ID,Date,No. of Input, [etc.]
Recall PT,6989807798167011841   ,2021-08-01,0,,0,0,0,,,,,[etc.]
Recall DE,6989807798167011841   ,2021-08-01,0,,0,0,0,,,,,[etc.]
```

but from nothing they decided to change to this:

```
The following data time zone is UTC+0
Queue Title,Queue ID,Date,No. of Input, [etc.]
Recall PT,6989807798167011841   ,2021-08-01,0,,0,0,0,,,,,[etc.]
Recall DE,6989807798167011841   ,2021-08-01,0,,0,0,0,,,,,[etc.]
```

And I need to continue with the previous output

So my approach was to create a script that reads all csv files in a folder, remove the first line and save them. But I am having the issue that in the new file that I create, python is saving the file with an extra **comma in the left**.  like this:

```
,Queue Title,Queue ID,Date,No. of Input, [etc.]
Recall PT,6989807798167011841   ,2021-08-01,0,,0,0,0,,,,,[etc.]
Recall DE,6989807798167011841   ,2021-08-01,0,,0,0,0,,,,,[etc.]
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# current directory csv files
csvs = [x for x in os.listdir('.') if x.endswith('.csv')]
# stats.csv -> stats
fns = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x))[0] for x in csvs]

d = {}
for i in range(len(fns)):
    d[fns[i]] = pd.read_csv(csvs[i], skiprows=1)

path = r'C:\Users\noob\Desktop\etc.\help\thank_you'

for k, v in d.items():
    v.to_csv(path+'\{}.csv'.format(k))
```

In the part, of saving to csv, I tried to had `index = False` but that would delete the columns

```
Recall PT 
Recall DE
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This looks like XY problem. If you are using pandas to read the csv, why not just skip first line? If you are using something different, you can always do the same one way or another. Maybe show the code that you use to read the files.

Comment: Included code is completely unrelated to problem described. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Hi buran - the code for reading the files is there, inside a for loop. I use the the command skiprows = 1, but when saving the files, python just adds an extra comma to the left. I understand why he does it, but I just can't overcome it.

Comment: HI Marek R - don't understand why the code is completely unrelated to the problem described. The code that I provided basically shows that I am doing. Importing all the files in the folder, removing the 1sr row, and saving the files. I just wanted to understand an way to overcome the issue of python providing a blank header for the index, without adding that extra comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `index=False` is the way to go. The first column gets deleted, because you most probably have at least one more comma in the data rows, than in the header row.

Try to edit the header to match the number of data columns.

Alternatively read like this:

```
d = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, skiprows=2)
```

and add the header manually.

Comment: The issue I think, is that my first column it's an index. For example, if I delete the 2 first headers as you suggest, and after change the columns names, I will get an Length mismatch error, because I will have more elements in my axis than column names. I basically I just want a way to put there the index, with a blank title. It makes sense for me that python adds up that extra comma, but I don't understand why I didn't use to receive like that the files. If I read an old file (correct output that I am looking for) in jupyter, first column it's an index, and it's correct like that